# Работа с Moviepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, видео

Требуется развернуть видео файл зеркально (mirror_x), почитав документацию к Moviepy написал следующий код, но что-то не работает выдавая ошибку:

> OSError: MoviePy error: the file 1.mp4 could not be found!
>   Please check that you entered the correct path.

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy
import os
import requests
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx

i = 0
directory = "D:\Документы\проекты\1 группа\заготовки" 
tema = 'D:\Документы\проекты\1 группа\обложка' # адрес обложки
oblojka = os.listdir(tema) 
files = os.listdir(directory) 
print(files[i])
print(oblojka[i])
volume = len(files) #пределяем размер массива
volume2 = len(oblojka) #пределяем размер массива
print(volume, volume2)
clip = VideoFileClip(files[i])
mclip = clip.fx(vfx.mirror_x)
mclip.write_videofile('mirror_fname.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дело было в том что таким способом скрипт не видит путь к файлу, поэтому надо его либо напрямую полностью вводить, либо через переменную с os.path.join

Answer (score 0):

я думаю дело в том, что вы указали директорию до видеофайлов, но не указали сами видео. даже в ошибке выданной питоном это написано.
если не ошибаюсь то формат команды для видеофайла должен выглядеть так

```
directory_video/video1.mp4`
```

в данном случае можно ввести переменную i и цикл for in range и в таком случае команда будет выглядеть так

```
directory_video/video{i}.mp4
```

можно попробовать автоматизировать процесс ренейминга для удобной работы, но проще ввести кортеж videofile_name и методом перебора редактировать видео по вашему запросу.
если найду время, то дополню ответ кодом
еще добавлю что ваш код кажется громоздким, почитайте про рефакторинг